# Can I use TLSv1.3 ciphers in TLSv1.2 session?

Tags: java, android, tls1.2, tls1.3, suite

Windows IIS Server 10 supported TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 on TLS 1.3.
But my application max TLS version TLS 1.2 . I can't send request to server due to tls mismatch.
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 is not found in my app. How can I use this CipherSuite ?

Note : My android project language is Java.

Comment: You can't. You will have to upgrade whatever you upgrade to get TLS 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The TLSv1.3 approach to ciphers isn't directly compatible with TLSv1.2, because the key exchange and signature is now treated separately ([which means you can't just use a TLSv1.3 cipher in TLSv1.2 and conversely](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Differences_with_TLS1.2_and_below)).

You can though pick equivalent ciphers for TLSv1.2 that match the functionality of TLSv1.3. All the options are listed on the IEEE site [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4).

If however all you are looking for is a strong set of options that support both TLSv1.3 and TLSv1.2, then I'd recommend taking a look at the Mozilla SSL [configuration](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) generator, which makes the process trivial to follow.